# Room Flow Always returns kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow@c8abe2e

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Initially i am getting list data from network and store it in room db.
It is One to Many Relationship. For that i have created Two Tables and One Relationship data class

Product Table :

```
@Entity(tableName = "Product")
data class Products (

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    var id : Int = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    var name  : String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_id")
    var category_id : String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "subcategory_id")
    var subcategory_id : String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "variants")
    var variants : List<Variants> = listOf()
)
```

Variant Table :

```
@Entity(tableName = "Variant")
data class Variants (

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    var id : Int  = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_id", index = true)
    var product_id : Int?  = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "measurement")
    var measurement : String?  = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "price")
    var price : String?  = null
)
```

Product With Variants ( Relationship between Two Tables )

```
  data class ProductWithVariants(
    @Embedded val product: Products,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "product_id"
    )
    val variants: MutableList<Variants> 
)
```

Dao : I get the ProductsWithVariants data using query and also filter by subcategory_id

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE subcategory_id=:subcat")
fun getProductWithVariants(subcat:Int): Flow<MutableList<ProductWithVariants>>
```

ViewModel :

```
var productListN: Flow<MutableList<ProductWithVariants>> = flowOf(mutableListOf())

fun networkproductlist() = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    productist.collectLatest {
        when (it) {
            Resource.Empty -> {
                Log.e("product", "" + "empty")
            }
            is Resource.Failure -> {
                Log.e("product", "" + "failure")
            }
            Resource.Loading -> {

            }
            is Resource.Success -> {
                val response = it.value
                for (i in 0 until response.data.size) {
                    val product: Products = response.data.get(i)
                    for (j in 0 until product.variants.size) {
                        variants = product.variants.get(j)
                    }
                }
                productsDao.deleteAllProducts()
                productsDao.insertProducts(response.data)
                productsDao.insertVariants(variants!!)
                val subcategoryid = SubCategoryList(response.data[0].subcategory_id!!.toInt())
                productsDao.insertSubCat(subcategoryid)
                productListN = productsDao.getProductWithVariants(response.data[0].subcategory_id!!.toInt())
                Log.e("product","product in room viewmodel : $productListN")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I said earlier , got the network response in success resource and insert products and variants in respective tables after that i insert the product subcategory in my database and get the list of  ProductWithVariants by hit the getProductWithVariants() on the next line ..

The Problem here is now - i always get kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow@f06e8a9 as a response of productlistN

Main Activity :

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    proadapter = ProductAdapter()
    binding.ProductRecyclerView.apply {
       adapter = proadapter
    }
}

lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    viewModel.productListN.collect {
        println("Received UserInfo List $it")
        proadapter.setMutableArraylist(it)
        proadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with getting `kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow@f06e8a9` as a response? Doesn't it work as intended? It seems it's how the Dao code is generated.

Comment: my flow collect not collect any data in main activity @Sergio and also i updated my Main Activity Collect Code Please see...why my data is not displayed in ui

Comment: please try to initialize `proadapter` and `binding.ProductRecyclerView` outside of `launch` function, and for collecting `Flow` data just use `lifecycleScope.launch { ... }`.

Comment: still i cannot get data in main activity itself from viewmodel @Sergio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a couple of issues in your code:

- In `ViewModel` you use `var productListN = ...` and then reinitialize it with a new object `productListN = productsDao.getProductWithVariants(response.data[0].subcategory_id!!.toInt())`. You shouldn't reinitialize it, you must use the same object. You can try to use `StateFlow` or `SharedFlow` to emit data:

```
val productListN: Flow<MutableList<ProductWithVariants>> = StateFlow(mutableListOf())
...
productListN.value = ...
```

- In `Activity` initialize `proadapter` and `binding.ProductRecyclerView` outside of `launch` function, and for collecting `Flow` data just use `lifecycleScope.launch { ... }`:

```
proadapter = ProductAdapter()
binding.ProductRecyclerView.apply {
    adapter = proadapter
}

lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.productListN.collect {
        println("Received UserInfo List $it")
        proadapter.setMutableArraylist(it)
        proadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```